# can't connect to vertica from a remote computer

Tags: amazon-ec2, vertica

I setup a one node instance using vertica community edition. I ran install like this:

```
/opt/vertica/sbin/install_vertica --hosts 127.0.0.1 --rpm /home/ec2-user/vertica-7.1.2-0.x86_64.RHEL5.rpm --dba-user dbadmin --data-dir /home/ec2-user/vertica1
```

install ran correctly...I created a db...loaded data...but did it all from the box.

My problem is that I can't connect to it from a remote computer. I can telnet on the ip address of the box on port 5433 but I can't connect to vertica. I this error:

```
vsql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "10.205.118.122" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

My guess is that I shoudl have done an "--hosts boxipaddress" instead of "--hosts 127.0.0.1"?

netstat shows this:

```
tcp 0 3331573 127.0.0.1:5433 127.0.0.1:49915 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 1442177 127.0.0.1:5433 127.0.0.1:49760 FIN_WAIT1
```

but I feel like it should show my ip adress instead of 127.0.0.1

am i on the right path here...and how do I fix this issue?

also, iptables is disabled...

I also changed my admintools.conf to looks like this:

```
[Cluster]
hosts = 10.205.118.122,127.0.0.1
[Nodes]
node0001 = 10.205.118.122,/home/ec2-user/vertica1,/home/ec2-user/vertica1
v_mdetest_node0001 = 10.205.118.122,/home/ec2-user/vertica1,/home/ec2-user/vertica1
v_mdetest2_node0001 = 10.205.118.122,/home/ec2-user/vertica1,/home/ec2-user/vertica1
[Database:mdetest]
restartpolicy = ksafe
port = 5433
path = /home/ec2-user/vertica1/mdetest
nodes = v_mdetest_node0001
[Database:mdetest2]
restartpolicy = ksafe
port = 5433
path = /home/ec2-user/vertica1/mdetest2/v_mdetest2_node0001_catalog
nodes = v_mdetest2_node0001
```

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to connect to EC2? Also, why did you manually change your `admintools.conf`?

Comment: Yep, I installed vertica on an EC2 instance (did not use the vertica AMI as we don't have access to it). Changed admintools conf to see if I could get it to work...

Comment: I don't understand how you don't have access to the AMI?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your security group in AWS.

- make sure you open the ports for those services.

Also don`t change **admintools.conf** not a good idea.

Also when installing vertica on AWS make sure you do it by using the private ip of the EC2 instance, not the localhost or the public ip(elastic).

For test only open all ports on the machine for Inbound and Outbound and from there you can eliminate ports based on the Vertica docs ports usage.

Good luck with that :)

Comment: so did a reinstall of vertica and I can telnet from my laptop to the ec2 instance on port 5433....but still can't connect via vsql from windows....